# Ubuntu 20.04 didn't recognize Apple CD/DVD player

Tags: usb, dvd, drive, apple

Is there a way to make my Apple USB Superdrive (External CD/DVD player)  work with Ubuntu 20.04? Plugged in and drive was not recognized.

Comment: How do you *know* the drive wasn't recognized?

Comment: Nothing showed up in the Activities bar (vertical bar on the left hand side of the screen). When I plugged in a flash drive I get an icon in the bar showing me it was recognized. More importantly, I tried t load a CD in the external drive and it was not pulled in to begin play.

Comment: The media not being pulled in suggests it isn't getting enough power. That aside no, it shouldn't show up.  Typically only with a (recognized) disc it will show up that media, not the drive itself.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with Apple Superdrive under Ubuntu 20.04.
And I found the below solution [here](https://cmos.blog/use-apples-usb-superdrive-with-linux/).

```
sudo apt-get install sg3-utils
sg_raw /dev/sr0 EA 00 00 00 00 00 01
```

Worked like a charm.